# How to port active configuration to module configuration

Tags: 8, configuration

**Scenario**: I have a website which was initially developed with a single site (A) in mind. Now, because reasons, I need to make this a multi-site setup (A & B). So, I have functionality in A I want to share with B. We built A with all config exported to it's config sync folder, which means all config is intertwined.

**Problem**: How would I go about converting all sharable configuration to modules, which would allow me to maintain the modules from one codebase in both A & B? Putting everything into `module_foobar/config/install/` will not work that easily for A, since it already has that config in it's active config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features): It basically does exactly what you want, it turns your existing configuration into a `module_foobar/config/install/`

Be aware though that Features merges config (it does add and update existing config, but it does not remove/delete unused config like core configuration management).

Comment: I've been trying to keep our workflow as light as possible. We've used Features as a necessary evil in Drupal 7 and would preferably avoid using Features.

Comment: I've never used Features in D7, but from what I've read it's working completely different (and way better) than in 7. In 8 you don't even need Features on the target site, it is only required on the source site and generates stand-alone modules with config. It now uses the API from core configuration management, I really think you should give it a second chance ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I've read the same notes; Features is completely different in D8. But you've now convinced me to give it another chance. I'll be back with conclusions. Thanks ;-)

Comment: Been fiddling with Features for hours now. It does look great, but still cannot get it to work since it creates config which creates a lot of `... already exist in active configuration` errors on a new installation. One, big, drama...

Comment: After a few days of research, I think you're right; features is the way to go and make modules reusable. Though, I'm still having major dependency issues. That might be a different issue, therefor I have created a new question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236449/how-to-export-referencing-nodes-in-separate-feature-packages